# Update/Insert an element in a nested stringified array of a mongoDB document

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

My collection has this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "7ZEc8dkbs4tLwhW24",
    "title" : "title",
    "json" :

        {
            \"cells\":[
                {
                    \"type\":\"model\",
                    \"size\":{\"width\":100,\"height\":40},
                    \"id\":\"11dc3b6f-2f61-473c-90d7-08f16e7d277a\",
                    \"attrs\":{
                        \"text\":{\"text\":\"content\"},
                        \"a\":{\"xlink:href\":\"http://website.com\",\"xlink:show\":\"replace\",\"cursor\":\"pointer\"}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Now I need to insert/update the field `json.cells.attrs.a` in my meteor app. All informations I got are `_id` (document ID) and `id` (id of element in cells). If `a` doesn't exist, the element should be created.

My attempt is not correct, as the query isn't looking for the elemID to get the correct element in the cells-array:

```
var linkObject = {"xlink:href":"http://newURL.com","xlink:show":"replace","cursor":"pointer"};
var docID = '7ZEc8dkbs4tLwhW24';
var elemID = '11dc3b6f-2f61-473c-90d7-08f16e7d277a'; // How to search for this 'id'?

var result = Collection.findOne({ _id: docID });
var json = JSON.parse(result.json);

// find id = elemID in 'json'
// add/update 'a'

// update json in mongoDB document
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are only adding the `docID` as criteria in your query. You must add the `elemID` to your query criteria. Then after that you can use [`dot.notation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/) and the [`$(Positional Operator)`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update the `a` property of the  `attrs` object. You can do it like this:

```
Collection.update(
    {"_id" : docID , "json.cells.id" : elemID },
    {$set: { "json.cells.$.attrs.a" : linkObject}}
}
```

[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set), will create the field if the field does not exist. You can use the [`$ Positional Operator`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) if you don't know the array position.

Comment: What does `false` and `true` mean?

Comment: Check out my edited answer, but they were options. You can see how to add options in mongo > 2.6 here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter

Comment: `db.collection.find({"_id" : '7ZEc8dkbs4tLwhW24' , "json.cells.id" : '11dc3b6f-2f61-473c-90d7-08f16e7d277a' }).pretty()` doesn't give me any result.

Comment: I just see that in the DB the data looks like: `"json" : "{\"cells\":[...` I think the slashes inside of `json` make some trouble, right?

Comment: in the mongodb shell can you post how your data looks when you run. 

`db.collection.find({"_id" : "7ZEc8dkbs4tLwhW24")})`

Comment: If I just use the _id to find the data, I get a result. But if I add the `son.cells.id` it doesn't work. But I think the data of `json` is stringified, So I can't access it directly :-( Think I first have to parse the string, update it and save it stringified back to the mongoDB...

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I think it can't be done directly to the DB, so I extracted `json` and did a `JSON.parse()`. After that I added/set the needed element and updated the new json to the DB.